# bootstrap-sass border-radius error in heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, twitter-bootstrap, sass

When deploying my app to heroku, i'm getting the following error:

```
2013-02-21T21:57:52+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS a
fter "          .border-radius": expected "{", was "();"
```

I updated bootstrap-sass since i found [this error](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/pull/40), but this doesn't solve the problem.
I'm using:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-colorpicker-rails'
```

I'm really at a loss here.

*It seems bootstrap-colorpicker-rails 0.2 was causing this, so i reverted back to 0.1 .

Comment: to me it looks like you have little typo here, can you show your CSS file here with the mentioned "border-radius" part in it? did your app work without errors on your localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have brackets around your `.border-radius` class. Not parens ().

```
.border-radius {
    Your CSS
}
```